# SVN: могу ли я счекаутиться в одну ветку, и скомититься в другую?

Tags: svn

Ситуация:
Начал делать задачу в trunk, однако понял что лучше бы сделать это в отдельной ветке. Кроме того, хотелось бы сохранить результаты труда на сервере на всякий случай, а комитить в trunk пока рано.

Вопрос: 
Что делать?
Могу ли создать branch и закомитить все туда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, делаете отдельную branch, и комитите свои изменения туда. Только не забывайте периодически делать merge своей branch и trunk.